# The Adventures of Jack #2

Tags: riddle, wordplay, story, geography

I hope you liked the first one, because Jack is back!

> This time Jack begins his journey in Asia,
>
> He chops off oxygen's head with a comma to get;
>
> A place where he sees Luke Skywalker's hand on the floor.
>
> So Jack goes touring for an hour and 40 minutes.
>
> When he is transported to the North Pole!
>
> Jack decides to remove lanthanum, to add another
>
> Why, praseodymium, must you come...
>
> And Jack is now in an entirely different country!
>
> Which country is Jack in?

Hint 1:

> You are looking for a specific country in Asia, not starting his adventure with the word **ASIA**.

Also, if you know something, post it as a partial answer, so you can help other people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This time Jack begins his journey in Asia,

> **Laos**

He chops off oxygen's head with a comma to get;
A place where he sees Luke Skywalker's hand on the floor.

> Remove the top part of O to get U, add a comma to get **LA, US**, which is where you can find Hollywood Walk of Fame with actor Mark Hamill's handprints.

So Jack goes touring for an hour and 40 minutes.
When he is transported to the North Pole!

> An hour 40 minutes is 100 minutes, or C in Roman numerals. Add that to LAUS to get (Santa) **Claus**, who lives on the North Pole according to US tradition.

Jack decides to remove lanthanum, to add another

> Claus minus La = **CUS**...

Why, praseodymium, must you come...

> Add Y (why) and Pr to get **Cyprus**

And Jack is now in an entirely different country!

Comment: This is the correct answer, well done. I was hoping someone would get the Mark Hamill bit, it was a bit cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

This time Jack begins his journey in Asia,

> ??

He chops off oxygen's head with a comma to get;

> ??

A place where he sees Luke Skywalker's hand on the floor.

> Bespin ?? Cloud City ???

So Jack goes touring for an hour and 40 minutes.

> 1h40min = 100min = C???

When he is transported to the North Pole!

> Alert, Nunavut

Jack decides to remove lanthanum, to add another

> Remove *LA* to become *ert*

Why, protactinium, must you come...

> Add *PA*  to *ert* and .....

And Jack is now in an entirely different country!
Which country is Jack in?

> Reorder to become PETRA, Jordan

Comment: Since we're adding and removing letters, feels like the "why" should be part of the solution somehow.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my error within the question, it should be praseodymium, not protactinium. I accidentally put in the wrong element. Also this has nothing to do with the correct answer. I will edit the element now.

Comment: @aguy Two common words that often get confused. It's like you're/your, its/it's, praseodymium/protactinium.

Comment: @aguy no worries, Great puzzle series keep-on going (: